# Conditional expectation and variance

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, variance

$$f_Y(y)\in U(0,1)$$
$$f_{X\mid Y=y}(y)\in \Gamma(3,y)$$
$$0\lt X\lt \infty,\quad 0\lt Y \lt 1 $$

Question: find $EX$ and $\operatorname{var}X$

My attempt:

$$EX=E(E(X\mid Y))=E(3Y)=\frac{3}{2}$$
$$\operatorname{var}X=E(X^2)-E(X)^2=E(9y^2)-\frac{9}{4}=9\int_0^1\mkern -8mu y^2 f_Y(y)\,dy-\frac{9}{4}=9*\frac{1}{3}-\frac{9}{4}=\frac{3}{4}$$

Solution in the book: $EX=\frac{3}{2}$ and $\operatorname{var}X=\frac{7}{4}$

I can't seems to find where my calculation went wrong, any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $E(X^2|Y)\ne E(X|Y)^2$.

Comment: Extra Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance

Comment: thanks alot, would help me greatly to remember this formula if you could provide an intuitive explaination over why varX=E(var(X∣Y))+var(E(X∣Y))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the hints.

$$\operatorname{var}X=E(\operatorname{var}(X\mid Y))+\operatorname{var}(E(X\mid Y))=E(3Y^2)+\operatorname{var}(3Y)= 3\int_0^1y^2f_Y(y)dy+9\operatorname{var}Y=1+\frac{9}{12}=\frac{7}{4}$$